# How to use > with Sass?

Tags: css, sass

How can I use > symbol with Sass? I want to override this with

```
nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

this:

```
nav {
   li {
       a:hover, a:focus { }
   }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as `>` has a more strict pathing. I need to use `>` with my Sass. How can I do it?

Ps. Don't want to rely on `!important`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you:

SASS:

```
nav {
   > li {
        > a:hover, > a:focus { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're after:

**SASS**

```
nav {
    > li {
        > a {
            &:hover, &:focus {text-decoration: none;background-color: #eee;}
        }
    }
}
```